# Information from a PickerView appears in another line of the TableView. How to solve?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello programmers friends. I have a situation I can not explain. I'll leave the prints on the screens and then describe what happened.

[-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uo5s.png)

[-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNBQa.png)

[-][3]

Initially I select the quantity in the pickerview and it changes in the UITextField field. Then when I scroll the screen, the 6 row of the table is with the PickerView information from row 1, and then when I roll the screen up, the data is lost. Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Comment: Cells are reused.  Please show you `cellForRowAt:` code.

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celulaProduto")! as! ProdutoCelula
            cell.didLoad()
            cell.produto = dados[indexPath.row]
            cell.id?.text = String(describing: dados[indexPath.row].id)
            cell.nomeDoProduto?.text = dados[indexPath.row].nome
            cell.descricaoDoProduto?.text = dados[indexPath.row].descricao
            cell.precoDoProduto?.text = dados[indexPath.row].preco
            cell.imagemProduto?.image = dados[indexPath.row].imagem
            cell.quantidade?.text = dados[indexPath.row].quantidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a quantity is selected, you need to persist that information in your data model. `UITableView` only creates enough rows to show what's visible on screen and it re-creates rows as they are scrolled into view. So you need to have the quantity information stored elsewhere to provide to the table view when it asks again for the row information. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: @PedroPaulo Glad to have been of assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

As Paulw11 mentioned, cells within a UITableView or a UICollectionView are reused, thus if you are manually creating the UIPickerView within the cell itself you have two options:

1) Rather than create the UIPickerView via code, subclass the UICollectionViewCell being used and add the UIPickerView either in the Xib / Storyboard(where ever you created the cell view).

2) In the prepareForReuse() function within a cell, check if the UIPickerView variable is not nil, and if it is not nil, then remove it and set it to nil.